# "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."

Tags: django, tastypie, django-csrf

I'm making RESTful API using Tastypie, and when I try to `POST/PUT/DELETE` a request it says:

> "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.".

It works fine with `GET`. I've read various threads on SO, saying:

- to delete the cookies
- or use `@csrf_exempt`
- or use `@method_decorator(csrf_exempt)`

but neither of it worked.

How can I over-pass this error?

**views.py**

```
class SnippetList(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                  generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request._dont_enforce_csrf_checks = True
        print request.DATA
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**serializer.py**

```
from django.forms import widgets
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Snippet, LANGUAGE_CHOICES, STYLE_CHOICES


class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from snippets import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^snippets/$', views.SnippetList.as_view()),
    url(r'^snippets/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.SnippetDetail.as_view()),
)

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

Comment: it seems, that you're using django-rest-framework but not Tastypie

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639169/csrf-failed-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

Change rest_framework default permissions to AllowAny in settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',),
...
}
```

Comment: I have `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` set to `rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated` because I only want to allow registered users to access the API. I'm looking for another way to fix this CSRF thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the CSRF token in your template, somewhere in your form :

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

See django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/csrf/#using-csrf).