# CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django 1.7 and django-rest-framework.

I made an API that returns me some JSON data putting this in my `settings.py`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    #   'rest_framework.renderers.XMLRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    #   'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    )
}
```

When I make GET calls, it returns me all the data, but when I try with PUT/PATCH I get:

```
--------Response Headers---------
Status Code: 403
Date: Wed, 29 Oct 2014 18:51:42 GMT
Vary: Cookie
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.8
Allow: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, HEAD, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json
---------------------------------

--------Response Body-----------
{"detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}
---------------------------------
```

This only happens when I am logged in, if I am anonymous I can PUT/PATCH correctly.

I have tried with `@csrf_exempt` and I got errors, I have included the `rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny` in the setting...

I have no idea what's going on. Does anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

When you are using [SessionAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#sessionauthentication), you are using Django's authentication which usually requires CSRF to be checked. Django REST Framework enforces this, only for `SessionAuthentication`, so you must pass the CSRF token in the `X-CSRFToken` header.

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) provides more information on retrieving the CSRF token using jQuery and sending it in requests. The CSRF token is saved as a cookie called `csrftoken` that you can retrieve from a HTTP response, which varies depending on the language that is being used.

If you cannot retrieve the CSRF cookie, this is usually a sign that you should not be using `SessionAuthentication`. I recommend looking into [TokenAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication) or [OAuth 2.0](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#oauth2authentication) depending on your needs.

Comment: I know I should give the CSRF Token when I am authenticated, but, actually I am using a .NET Windows Forms Application to communicate with this API, and it makes the GET call by HTTPRequest and HTTPResponse methods, I have no idea how could I get the CSRF Token in this situation, I am not using AJAX nor HTML Forms.
**EDIT** The .NET app receives plain text in JSON format, and it return the same

Comment: You are all right, with the cookie I can handle the csrftoken and put it back in the header data, so i can make PUT/PATCH calls if I am logged in. THANK YOU!

Comment: @AlexLordMordor Can you explain a little bit your solution please? and why it didn't work when you were a logged-in user, but in annonymous ways it worked. (I have EXACTLY the same problem)

Comment: When you use SessionAuthentication, by default django requires two "keys" one of them could be found in the cookies when a logged-in user is active and the other is the csrf-token, if they do not match, then an error is raised, so, there is the documentation like @Kevin said to make it authenticate in the correct way.

Comment: An other way to implement this can be found in this post: http://blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html, in the section "Interlude: AngularJS + CSRF Protection". In this case using AngularJS

Comment: when I moved the     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
before the     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
it stopped crying for the CSRF token for my DRF_extensions requests. `Django==2.1.7`, `djangorestframework==3.9.2`, `drf-extensions==0.4.0`

Comment: I just spent the last half hour trying to find the header key, `X-CSRFToken`. I tried literally everything else. Thank you!

Answer (score 34):

I think it is a cookie issue.

Permanent Solution: If you are using Postman, First, clear the existing cookies by clicking 'X' s. Then add correct cookie.

Temporary Solution (for debugging): Try this in your `settings.py`:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
]
```

Comment: clear cookies solved my problem

Comment: I make use of Insomnia and clearing the cache solved the problem

Comment: Great answer, link to the exact setting of this variable: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme

Comment: Whenever testing CSRF, using anything other than a browser is not fruitful and can lead to misleading investigation. The reason is that tools like Postman, Insomnia or Curl bypass all sorts of CSRFs restrictions as this is something enforced by a browser. So one might believe things are working when in fact they are not

Comment: Changing session Authentication to basic authentication solved the problem.

Answer (score 23):

This is what i did to solve it, i included csrf token to the form and using jquery/ javascrip got the csrf token like this when document loaded

```
var $crf_token = $('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').attr('value');
```

the included it on jquery headers as follow

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/api/endpoint/",
            data: newEndpoint,
            headers:{"X-CSRFToken": $crf_token},
            success: function (newEnd) {
                console.log(newEnd);
                add_end(newEnd);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("There was an error")
            }
        });
```

Comment: This works. In case anyone is wondering, the value for $crf_token comes from the csrftoken cookie picked up during Basic Auth login.

Answer (score 16):

1- Search for the Cookie header

[image]

2- Separate the csrftoken from the sessionid

3- Add the X-CSRFToken={..the csrftoken that you extracted in step 2..} see below

[image]
4- Post again

Answer (score 7):

We had this problem and it turned out to be Postman's fault. They were automatically sending `csrftoken` and `sessionid` default values which we weren't passing in the header. Following this tutorial helped fix the issue: https://avilpage.com/2019/02/django-tips-csrf-token-postman-curl.html

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution that worked for me is:

Add CSRF token in the headers of the AJAX POST call, and this can be done by including this one line of code

```
headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}' },
```

And this line should be added above the `success`

Answer (score 3):

Get token from cookie:

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

var csrftoken = readCookie('csrftoken');
```

Send token in headers POST request:

```
  this.$http.post(server,{params: {foo: 'bar'}}, {headers: {"X-CSRFToken":csrftoken }}).then(function (response) {
            this.response = response.data;
        },
        function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

Comment: This is the only valid answer that has actual code.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to solve this error, I found on [here](https://overcoder.net/q/17018/django-rest-framework-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-csrf). It works for me perfectly.

Steps:

Inherit the SessionAuthentication class:

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication 

class CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):

    def enforce_csrf(self, request):
        return  # To not perform the csrf check previously happening
```

Then in the APIView you have created, do this:

```
class Object(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
```

This will keep you logged-in and your CSRF token will no longer be checked for this APIView.

Comment: And you've opened yourself up to CSRF attacks.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it creating a custom middleware in my project like this:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class DisableCSRFMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        setattr(request, '_dont_enforce_csrf_checks', True)
```

And then I called it in my settings.py like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    # "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "todoproject.middlewares.DisableCSRFMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]
```

It works for me!

Answer (score 2):

If your using the `djangorestframework`

the default setting is

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

`comment` or `remove` the `SessionAuthentication` like this

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

Comment: after that it start to say `detail: 'Authentication credentials were not provided.'`

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when i tried to send POST request using Postman:

[image]

I tried the same with cURL and it works:

```bash
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/register/ | jq
```

[image]

To fix this using Postman you need to click on cookies and delete them:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```js
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I'd wrapped the views with `csrf_exempt` and was still encountering errors. It turned out that I was getting the URL wrong, so it was resolved to a "not found" callback (which wasn't exempt from CSRF) and was hence throwing an exception before I could be told that the URL was wrong.

Comment: For me it was simply that I'd forgotten to add the trailing '/' to my URL. Like @kokociel said, the issue was nothing to do with CSRF and instead that the URL wasn't resolving to any of my endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

When you host django website on Apache server.
Djando rest framework with TokenAuthentication and SessionAuthentication will get

> CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect

To fix this open Apache configuration file - httpd.conf Add following line:

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// USING AJAX TO UPDATE DATABASE THROUGH REST API
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this happened to me while testing rest-auth registration using postman
this happened because postman was sending incorrect headers some old cookies and wrong content type i think it is some kind of a bug or i was ding it wrong

**Solution:**  so i disabled the default headers

manually entered content type and the json body(POST request)

then re-enabled the required headers

Answer (score 1):

In settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
...
...
...
'rest_framework.authtoken',
...
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

in project urls.py

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views

urlpatterns = [
    ....
    path('api-token-auth/',views.obtain_auth_token,name='api-token-auth')

]
```

Open terminal as

```
$ pip3 install httpie
$ python3 manage.py createsuperuser # if not created
$ http POST http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/ username="username" password = "password"   # You will get token key (Just copy it) ex:a243re43fdeg7r4rfgedwe89320
```

> > You token key will be also automatically saved in your databases

Go to postman header (like in example)
Ex: [screenshot from postman ,where and how to paste accessed toke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPjcM.png)

Then insert you token key.

> [You can take reference to get token key from this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFcnQbOfbUU)

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue while testing API in postman, I solved it by cleaning cache in Postman for that request.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, I've wrapped my URLs under `csrf_exempt` method as -

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

url(r'^api/v1/some-resource$', csrf_exempt(SomeApiView.as_view())),
```

Answer (score -10):

django1.8 python2.7

```
{
    "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
}
```

I fix it by using other httpmethod;
oh, I face it again, this time is because I paste it, there are some invisible characters

Comment: [Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)