# Django - Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with creating a simple form that uses {% csrf_token%}.

Template with form:

```
<form action="{% url 'library:my_view' %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
        # ...
        path('some_page', views.my_view, name='my_view'),
]
```

views.py

```
def my_view(request):
        used_method = str(request.method)
        return render(request, 'library/some_template.html', {'test': used_method})
```

Template with result (some_template.html):

`{{test}}`

The server gives me the message:

> Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): / Library / some_page
>   
>  "POST / library / some_page HTTP / 1.1" 403 2513

or (when i use a different browser):

> Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /library/some_page 
>  "POST
>   /library/some_page HTTP/1.1" 403 2868

The form works correctly when I disable protection by `@csrf_exempt` decorator . Where is a problem?

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Do you have ''django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'' in your settings MIDDLEWARE list?

Comment: Yes, I do. This is the default setting. I didnt change it.

Comment: Do you have `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=True` in your `settings.py` and accessing your development server over http instead of https?

Comment: Dunno, your code is ok, it's probably some settings, cache, or similar

Comment: CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True/False - no diference
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True/False - no diference
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False - no diference, True - access HTTPS and I cant connet with localhost at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639169/csrf-failed-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Here you are creating a empty form. what are you rendering inside the form? Did you create any forms.py file?

```
<form action="{% url 'library:my_view' %}" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I have not created any forms. py file.
I'm working with the Django 2.2 tutorial and this file has not been introduced yet.
I used a empty form because I wanted to explain my problem on the simplest example. Can it matter?

When I add inputs that do something, the problem looks the same.
The form works if I use @csrf_exempt and does not work with the token enabled.