# CSRF token missing or incorrect - Django 2.2

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin, csrf-token

I try to create an admin user in my application, but even I do not include any code, it gives the error 'CSRF token missing or incorrect'. I can't find what to do. Can anyone solve this problem?

I tried all the suggestions from my friends, and Django documentation, but none of them could solve it.

Actually, there is no need to paste my code, because as I mentioned before even without any HTML templates it is not possible to create an admin user.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDEk1.png)

Comment: You didn't like this answer?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639169/csrf-failed-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect , cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089224

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26639169/csrf-failed-csrf-token-missing-or-incorrect)

Comment: Can you add any screenshot or details about the problem which you have faced?

Comment: @FatemaT.Zuhora, I added the screenshot to the post. But please note that even I start a project from scratch, with no template or code, I got the same error.

Comment: So let me clear one thing, yo just start a new project and want to visit `localhost:8000/admin`. After submitting the username and password you saw the following error. Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admin login normally does require a CSRF token, but that's usually all taken care for you. Despite being as you have faced the following problem, this **could be generating from your browser extensions**.

- Check your browser's cookies to see if there is a CSRF token present
- Try clearing all the cookies, disabling the browser extensions and refreshing

OR just try from another browser which does not have any extensions and cookies are present.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was my browser.

Comment: @BekirYunusov Please, accept the answer as you think it solved your problem.